# Can I recover data from a RAID5 after accidental changed of disk order?

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid5

An intern yesterday accidentally changed the disk order, now we get there error, "Following containers have missing required members and cannot be configured. Container #0 RAID-5" Then no boot device found.

Is it possible,

1. To restore the raid?
2. Recover the data in it?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried putting them back in the correct order?

Comment: Yes I tried, I get the same error.

Comment: Couldn't you at least tell what controller you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is possible to restore the RAID depends on the controller which I don't know anything about. Have a look at the manual and contact the manufacturer's support.

If that does not lead to any good result the next question arises: Can the data be accessed. That should be possible in general without too much pain as there is probably no metadata in between on the disks. So you "just" need to find out where the data starts on the disks and how it is distributed.

With this knowledge you can set up a DM device (talking Linux here) which points for every sector to the respective disk (and sector). This will not be possible for the whole disk at once as DM is probably not designed for having millions of sector definitions per device. And even a million of them just get us: half a gigabyte.

So if this turns out to work in principle then you have to set up a DM device of reasonable size (I have no idea where the limit is, this may mainly depend on RAM or perhaps internal DM limits), copy that virtual device's content to a completely seperate disk, remove the virtual device and recreate it with a bigger offset (shifted by just the size of the DM device).

This should get you your data back. But for obvious reasons this is gonna take some time.